# ScriptableObject, added a field, Assets not updating, how to?

Tags: unity-game-engine, serialization, scriptable-object

Newly added field in ScriptableObject class not being put into assets of its type. Is this something todo with how Scriptable Objects work? Is there a way to update a scriptable object asset without losing existing info in already populated fields?

My ScriptableObject class has a bunch of strings for animation:

```
public class SO_AnimStringNames : ScriptableObject {
public string FirstAnim;
public string SecondAnim;
public string ThirdAnim;
}
```

I've created a ScriptableObject asset via this class, and added names to the strings, and used it as data within another object type, that uses those strings.

Just now, added a fourth string to the ScriptableObject class, so now it looks like this:

```
public class SO_AnimStringNames : ScriptableObject {
public string FirstAnim;
public string SecondAnim;
public string ThirdAnim;
public string FourthAnim; // newly added field
}
```

but it's not seen/updated within the ScriptableObject asset, and there's no obvious way to update this asset.

Is this a limitation of ScriptableObjects, or is something else wrong?

Comment: Should happen ... Any compiler errors that would hinder Unity from recompilation? How exactly did you create the asset? (I suppose this is not the complete code?)

Comment: This was the problem! I'd added something in another file, a new abstract method, and hadn't cascaded down all the overrides needed. Missed two, and didn't think anymore of it, whist doing other things.

Comment: Thank you, @derHugo, feel like a right muppet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a bit confused with your issue here, so...

**Option 1:**
I just tried what you did, but I added the `CreateAssetMenu` attribute on top of your class, someone mentioned you probably didn't share all of your code but in theory this is how it should be looking:

```c#
[CreateAssetMenu(fileName ="NewAnimStringNames",menuName ="Animation Names")]
public class SO_AnimStringNames : ScriptableObject
{
    // made an instance with these three first
    public string FirstAnim;
    public string SecondAnim;
    public string ThirdAnim;
    // then added the fourth variable, the instance I created previously updates correctly 
    //and keeps the values I set on the other three
    public string FourthAnim;
}
```

Is that how your `ScriptableObject` actually looks and you're creating them from Assets/Create menu or with right click on your assets plus create menu?

**Option 2:**
They also mentioned that maybe you have another issue that is not allowing Unity to recompile leading to your `ScriptableObject` updating itself with the new field? Please check the console for any other issues.

Comment: Option 2 it is!